# Add another argument to route for DRF

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

There are set of API endpoints generated by default by Django Rest Framework. Example this one :

```
^api/ ^ ^provinces/(?P<pk>[^/.]+)/$ [name='province-detail']
```

produces `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/provinces/02/` which is fine.
It uses the actual code bellow:

```
class ProvinceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """ Serializer to represent the Province model """
    class Meta:
        model = Province
        fields = ("name", "code")
```

I want to add another route, so that I can have another endpoint for example:

```
^api/ ^ ^provinces/(?P<pk>[^/.]+)/(?P<product>[^/.]+)/$ [name='province-product-detail']
```

So that I can do like this `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/provinces/02/apple/` and access the second argument in a method of the serializer. I'm trying to do like this :

```
class ProvinceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """ Serializer to represent the Province model """
    class Meta:
        model = Province
        fields = ("name", "code")

    @detail_route(methods=['post'])
    def set_product(self, request, product=None):
        return product
```

Comment: I think ore important then the serializer is the Views. Can you please post yours views?

Answer (score 0):

I've find out I was using the @detail_route in the wrong place. We just have to do this:

```
class ProvinceDistrictViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows users to view or edit province.
    """
    queryset = Province.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProvinceDistrictsSerializer

    # For get provinces
    @detail_route(methods=['get'], url_path='(?P<product>\d+)')
    def update_product(self, request, pk, product=None):
        """ Updates the object identified by the pk and add the product """
        queryset = Province.objects.filter(pk=pk)
        serializer = ProvinceDistrictsSerializer(queryset, many=True, context={'product': product})
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```